# How much sleep is required to restore maximum cognitive functioning?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, intelligence, performance, sleep

**Background:** Recently I have really messed up my sleep schedule due to my procrastination. The internet points to some very basic conclusions but I would like to see actual experiments on effects of sleep on cognitive functions.

#### Questions

- What is the absolute minimum hours of sleep one needs to completely restore brain functionality to peak levels?
- How much sleep is required for muscle rebuilding processes?
- How does this amount of sleep affect learning process, memory recall, and ability to infer relationships?

Comment: vote to close: aside from being self-help, this question cannot be answered adequately. 'required' amount of sleep will vary with the individual, and is certainly not a step function. also, what are 'peak levels' of brain functionality? if we broaden the criteria required for an answer, then the question is simply asking for a review of sleep studies on cognition.

Comment: I closed this question as I think it indeed is too broad, you could narrow it down and already look up some initial resources. You mention 'the internet points to some very basic conclusions', which ones? Perhaps verify first whether those are correct and ask about that? I [started a discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10902121#10902121) since it got so many up votes, so others might overrule me. For a more focused example of a sleep-related question you could check out: http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/868/21

Comment: P.s. some of the papers I link to in that question might get you started reading up on the subject.

Comment: I'm not sure how this question is any more self help than...well almost all of the other ones here.   He asks specific questions that can be answered - although I do think he should make them more qualitative rather than quantitative - but still keeping that aspect in.

Comment: From a site growth perspective, you also have to consider   what the people want too...if this type of question got that many votes then that means people in general are interested in it.  We'll rank for it in the search engines and get more traffic, and thus the site will grow more.  I probably could of reworded it but, agh I got so much other stuff going on now.

Comment: @StevenJeuris Please reopen, maybe someone can answer it.

Comment: @user1477388 Feel free to edit the question to improve it, simultaneously bumping it. This way it might receive reopen votes. As it is the question did not change, so I see no reason to reopen.