# Adaptation to Discrete Perturbation in Sleep?

Tags: sleep

Generally, are there and how long do lingering affects of polar sleep patterns affect someone? For example, assume someone slept for 2 hours one day and then slept for 14 hours the next. Their 2 day average would be 8, an unofficial heuristic for optimal sleep length. However, intuitively, I feel that their cognition would notably be different for a while because of these polarized events. Is this true? And if so, what are the basis for this, and how long do these effects last assuming someone got 8 hours a sleep religiously over the next few weeks?

By changes in their cognition (the ones I feel "intuitively"), I mean like a lower fidelity of memory, slower reaction times, but still the ability to function normally in a group setting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you catch up on sleep over the weekend?](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/868/can-you-catch-up-on-sleep-over-the-weekend)

Comment: This may also be a duplicate, but has no answers: https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/10407/how-to-compare-cumulative-sleep-debts

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg - The question is subtly different in terms of the daily distribution of sleep.

Comment: it seems like this is a widely-asked question with no solid answers to date.

Comment: @honi Are there any collections recent literature with theories?