# Sleep deprivation effect on brain

Tags: sleep

I have a doubt reg. sleep deprivation.

I did not sleep for past 24 hours(Because I did not feel sleepy),but slept the next day for full 8 hours. I do not feel the difference So my questions are,

1. Should I compensate this 8 hours(which I did not sleep)?
2. Will this damage my brain(If it happens once) ?

Comment: As a starting point, you may want to look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_debt

Comment: Thanks I finally got my answer [here](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/868/can-you-catch-up-on-lost-sleep).You can mark this as a duplicate. Please do not delete this.