# Does night-sleep-deprivation have any effect on cognitive performance?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, intelligence, sleep, working-memory, long-term-memory

Sleeping during the day might lead e.g. to vitamin D deficiency. But I am interested in what effects might night-sleep-deprivation have on cognitive faculties.

Does sleeping during the day and absolutely not getting night sleep have an effect on working memory, long-term memory, intelligence level, processing speed, etc.?

Comment: Related: [Can you catch up on sleep over the weekend?](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/868/21) As some sources in the question I formulated there indicate, in short, _yes_. :)

Answer (score 4):

According to [this article](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/the-land-nod/201508/when-working-shifts-works-against-you), yes it does have various symptoms including cognitive deficiencies that make us more prone to errors and less efficient :

> Circadian rhythms biologically program us to stay awake during
>   daylight hours and sleep at night. Shift work goes directly against
>   what our bodies desire to do, and those that struggle with this may
>   suffer from shift work sleep disorder (SWSD).
>
> ... symptoms may include headaches, weight gain, gastrointestinal
>   issues, fatigue, attention and concentration issues, work absenteeism,
>   irritability and depression. ... Worst of all, shift workers are at a
>   significantly greater risk for vehicular accidents and mistakes at
>   work.
>
> The ideal situation is to maintain a steady sleep-wake schedule seven
>   days a week, allowing for 7-8 hours of sleep. Although difficult to
>   follow, it can be extremely helpful to help reset circadian rhythms.
>   It can be especially tough on days off, when desires to socialize in
>   the daytime and maintain more “normal” sleep periods kick in.

[Additonal reference](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2904525/)

Comment: I wouldn't consider "psychology today" to be a reliable source.

Comment: @Cauchy I have added [additional reference](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2904525/)