# Are there any long term cognitive impairments from prolonged period reduced sleep?

Tags: sleep, brain-development, brain

What are the consequences of chronic lack of sleep? For example, insomniacs are known to sleep less than normal sleeping individuals.

I am wondering if there are any long term cognitive impairments from reducing sleep time to, say 4h instead of the normally recommended 8 hours in the long run, say for a year or so?

Comment: [The websites I link to in my more specific question](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/868/21) mentions a couple of cognitive impairments, and I also list articles which state how some of them are overcome in the short term. Perhaps these sources can help you formulating a better sourced, well-defined, question? Specifically, _"attention-dependent neural processes do not normalize after this period of time in habitually short sleeping individuals and may require longer recovery periods"_.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has some good information on this issue. Search for:

Effects of sleep deprivation on cognitive performance

In summary, 'yes', sleep deprivation can have a multitude of negative consequences on your cognitive abilities, like weakening your ability to handle complex cognitive tasks.

Comment: More precisely there's [an entire Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effects_of_sleep_deprivation_on_cognitive_performance) on the topi. The search prhase is also good on google, first hit for me is this review article: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2656292/